# Bound remapping of contiguous multidimensional array in Fortran with ifort 16

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, intel-fortran

I have a problem with index remapping that occurs in ifort 16, but does not occur in ifort 14 or in gfortran (exact version numbers are listed below). The problem occurs in the following test program:

```
program remap_problem

  implicit none

  type :: tp
    real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: trg_in
  end type tp

  real, dimension(:,:,:), allocatable, target :: trg_out

  type(tp), target :: instance
  real, dimension(:,:), pointer :: ptr

  allocate(instance%trg_in(3,4,5))
  allocate(trg_out(3,4,5))

  ptr(0:2,0:3) => instance%trg_in(:,:,2)
  ptr(0:2,0:3) => trg_out(:,:,2)

end program remap_problem
```

There is a rule in Fortran that you can only redefine the indices (done with the 0:2,0:3) if the target is contiguous or rank one. In this example, the target subarray is contiguous because the last index is the slowest in Fortran.

With ifort 14 or gfortran, it compiles as normal.
But ifort 16 complains that the target array in the derived type is not contiguous and I get the following error:

```
error #8527: If a bound remapping list is specified, data target must be simply contiguous or of rank one.   [TRG_IN]
```

But, the error does not occur for `trg_out. So`, somehow, ifort 16 does not recognize the `instance%trg_in(:,:,2)` as contiguous because it is in a derived type. I tried adding the keyword `contiguous` here and there and replace `allocatable` with `pointer`, but nothing seems to work.

A workaround is:

```
  ptr(0:2,-4:3) => instance%trg_in
```

which put the desired elements on the correct indices, but that is dirty. Is there a correct way to fix this issue, or do I have to wait for a compiler update.

The versions of my iforts and gfortran are:

ifort (IFORT) 14.0.2 20140120
ifort (IFORT) 16.0.0 20150815
GNU Fortran (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2

Comment: This looks like a question to the vendor to me. Steve Lionel comes here from time to time, but I don't know if he can still raise issues with Intel staff. In my opinion it is a bug (regression) and should be reported at the official forum.

Comment: Your code compiles for me with PGI 15.10

Comment: Compiles in ifort 18.0 as well. (I don't have 17.0 handy.)